# In how many ways can you sit 5 people in a row of 20 seats if no 2 can sit together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've seen the simpler problem of just sitting 2 people in non consecutive seats. In that case, I would subtract from the total number of ways to sit the 2 persons the number of ways of sitting them together.

In this harder version of the problem,I've though of the same thing, but now considering the case were 2, 3, 4 or 5 sit together.
But that seems to count duplicate cases.

Comment: Hint:  try to turn this into a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem by considering the gaps between people.

Comment: ... though you may have to invent unoccupied seats at the end to complete the analogy

Answer (score 3):

Sit the $5$ people in $16$ seats, and then add a seat between each pair.

This gives $\binom{16}{5}$ as the answer.

Comment: +1. Or $5!\binom {16}{5}$ if the order of the people matters,

Answer (score 2):

Seat $5$ people ($A, B, C, D$ and $E$) first and then add $4$ seats (denoted by $s$) between them so none of them are seated adjacent to each other. Now you are left with $11$ seats to put in $6$ places - $4$ places between them or at two ends (denoted by $\uparrow$).

$\uparrow As \uparrow Bs \uparrow Cs \uparrow Ds \uparrow E\uparrow$

Now the problem is equivalent to finding the number of $6-$tuples of non-negative integers whose sum is $11$ for which you use stars and bars method. Lastly, there are $5!$ ways to arrange people in the their seats.